# Some pages are randomly served as XML/feed and not as HTML

Tags: joomla-3.x, xml, cache, header-tags

I'm having this random issue:

In some pages (not always the same, and without a readable pattern), **the pages are served as XML/feed and not as HTML**.

What I've found out is that the correct

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

is generated as

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8" />`

I'm using an Apache 2.2.15 server, and PHP 5.3.17, Joomla 3.5.1, and my guess is that this is something related to the cache of Joomla (currently using progressive cache, file, 15 minutes), and also a cache control plugin [CacheControl](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/cachecontrol).

Does anyone have/had the same problem?

How do I solve this?

Comment: The second should on be served if ?format=rss is added to the URL. Have you got RSS enabled on your site?

Comment: I have RSS enabled, but not in the homepage, which is "suffering" from this issue as well, and I haven't mand any change that would justify this behaviour.

Comment: can you post a link to your site?

Comment: I don't have permission from the company to share the link.